# NHibernate criteria to query parent objects with at least one child object?

Tags: nhibernate, criteria, subquery, correlated-subquery

In my project, `Lines` can be grouped and a `Group` has a type which can be either `Crossing` (1) or `Parallel` (2). I need to find all lines which has at least one group of a specified type (in this case, 1). The Id of a given line can be either on column `LineA` or `LineB` of a group. Here is where i got so far:

```
Criteria crit = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Line), "ln");

DetachedCriteria count = DetachedCriteria.For<Group>()
.SetProjection(Projections.CountDistinct("Id"))
.Add(Expression.Or(
    Expression.EqProperty("LineA", "ln.Id"),
    Expression.EqProperty("LineB", "ln.Id")))
.Add(Expression.Eq("GroupTypeId", 1));

crit.Add(Subqueries.Gt(0, count));
```

Comment: Your query looks OK. Are you looking for a better way for doing this or your query does not work as it should?

Comment: it doesn't work. Throws an exception but I can't remember the message. I got it working and will post the answer

Comment: You should take the time to check what exception you were receiving and post it with your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it working!

```
crit.Add(Expression.Sql(
  "EXISTS(select 1 from Group" +
  "WHERE ({alias}.Id=LineA OR {alias}.Id=LineB)"+
    "AND GroupTypeId = ?)", (int) type, NHibernateUtil.Int32));
```

`{alias}` is a placeholder for the object being queried.

Comment: Not really using Criteria though is it.